# Plotly graph with line disappear issue

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

In Jupyter Notebook, I am drawing 10 sets of line graphs using plotly and each set of graph is composed with 14 sub-graphs (facets). However when I start running the 9th graph, the 1st graph from top havng all the lines disappeared. When i go back to run the 1st graph, then another graph having all the lines disappear. I kept trying this in circles, and nothing stops this happen. Is this due to some kind of memory limitation of my browser? Is there any configuration I can do?  The sample graph below is not exact what I was drawing (mine have much more lines and facets than this one), just using this graph as an idea. When drawing many sets of graphs like this, the ones at the beginning became to show only the background, the lines on top all disappeared. However if I hoover my mouse on the space, I can still see numbers etc without seeing the line.

[image]

Comment: This question will be pretty challenging to debug without a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Understand, I am mostly seeking for answers from folks who ever experienced this type issue in their work.